# LangChain always shows the same template and content

Tags: nlp, langchain

LangChain always shows the same template and content, even if I don't mention anything. I have tried killing and restarting the Kernel, however, this didn't work.

```py
chain = RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain.from_chain_type(
    llm,
    chain_type="stuff",
    retriever=db.as_retriever()
)
print(chain)
```

```
Out:RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain(memory=None, callbacks=None, callback_manager=None, verbose=False, tags=None, metadata=None, combine_documents_chain=StuffDocumentsChain(memory=None, callbacks=None, callback_manager=None, verbose=False, tags=None, metadata=None, input_key='input_documents', output_key='output_text', llm_chain=LLMChain(memory=None, callbacks=None, callback_manager=None, verbose=False, tags=None, metadata=None, prompt=PromptTemplate(input_variables=['summaries', 'question'], output_parser=None, partial_variables={},
template='Given the following extracted parts of a long document and a question, create a final answer with references ("SOURCES"). \nIf you don\'t know the answer, just say that you don\'t know. Don\'t try to make up an answer.\nALWAYS return a "SOURCES" part in your answer.\n\nQUESTION: Which state/country\'s law governs the interpretation of the contract?\n=========\n
Content: This Agreement is governed by English law and the parties submit to the exclusive jurisdiction of the English courts in  relation to any dispute (contractual or non-contractual) concerning this Agreement save that either party may apply to any court for an  injunction or other relief to protect its Intellectual Property Rights.\nSource: 28-pl\nContent: No Waiver. Failure or delay in exercising any right or remedy under this Agreement shall not constitute a waiver of such (or any other)  right or remedy.\n\n11.7 Severability. The invalidity, illegality or unenforceability of any term (or part of a term) of this Agreement shall not affect the continuation  in force of the remainder of the term (if any) and this Agreement.\n\nWell I know this nation.\nSource: 34-pl\n=========\nFINAL ANSWER: The president did not mention Michael Jackson.\nSOURCES:\n\nQUESTION: {question}\n=========\n{summaries}\n=========\n
FINAL ANSWER:', template_format='f-string', validate_template=True),
llm=HuggingFaceHub(cache=None, verbose=False, callbacks=None, callback_manager=None, tags=None, metadata=None, client=InferenceAPI(api_url='https://api-inference.huggingface.co/pipeline/text2text-generation/mrm8488/t5-base-finetuned-question-generation-ap', task='text2text-generation', options={'wait_for_model': True, 'use_gpu': False}), repo_id='mrm8488/t5-base-finetuned-question-generation-ap', task=None, model_kwargs={'temperature': 0.9, 'max_new_tokens': 700}, huggingfacehub_api_token='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'), output_key='text', output_parser=StrOutputParser(), return_final_only=True, llm_kwargs={}), document_prompt=PromptTemplate(input_variables=['page_content', 'source'], output_parser=None, partial_variables={}, template='Content: {page_content}\nSource: {source}', template_format='f-string', validate_template=True), document_variable_name='summaries', document_separator='\n\n'), question_key='question', input_docs_key='docs', answer_key='answer', sources_answer_key='sources', return_source_documents=False, retriever=VectorStoreRetriever(tags=['Chroma', 'HuggingFaceEmbeddings'], metadata=None, vectorstore=<langchain.vectorstores.chroma.Chroma object at 0x7f56d774ae30>, search_type='similarity', search_kwargs={}), reduce_k_below_max_tokens=False, max_tokens_limit=3375)
```

The template and content should be blank, or should be custom.

Comment: The default cache is stored in-memory. This means that if you restart your application, the cache will be cleared.

Comment: @ZKS  Restarting the application didn't worked for me. Can You help me with clearing chain cache with any other method?

Answer (score 2):

Reference - https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/6982

The default prompt template for the RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain object can be customized to suit your specific needs. In the context shared, a new PromptTemplate is created with a different format. You can use this new template when initializing the RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain object. Here's how you can do it:

from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate

```
    prompt_template = """Question: {question}
    Answer in Italian:"""
    PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
        template=prompt_template, input_variables=["context", "question"]
    )

    chain_type_kwargs = {"prompt": PROMPT}
    qa = RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain.from_chain_type(
        llm=llm_chat,
        chain_type="stuff",
        retriever=db_test.as_retriever(),
        chain_type_kwargs=chain_type_kwargs
    )
```

This way, the RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain object will use the new prompt template instead of the default one. Additionally, the new context shared provides examples of other prompt templates that can be used, such as DEFAULT_REFINE_PROMPT and DEFAULT_TEXT_QA_PROMPT. These can be used in a similar way to customize the prompt for different use cases.

In the context shared, it's also shown how to use the RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain in a ConversationalRetrievalChain. This can be useful if you want to generate questions and answers in a conversational manner.